# Deleting data from table using jQuery and SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is some part of my code, I'm using an ajax post and delete data, everything works fine, except that the data are not being deleted from my database. What am I doing wrong?
here we go:

File view.php

```
<table class='uk-table uk-table-striped'><tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Ano</th>
<th>Grau</th>
<th>Serie</th>
<th>Curso</th>
<th>Instituição</th>
<th>Cidade</th>
<th>Estado</th>
<th>Excluir?</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#load').hide();
});

$(function() {
$(".delete").click(function() {


 if (confirm("Tem certeza?"))
                {
                    var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var data = 'id=' + id ;

$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "delete.php",
    data: data,
   cache: false,
   success: function(){ 
    row.slideUp('slow', function() {$(row).remove();});

  }


 });


 }

return false;
    });
});


echo "<tr id='".$historico['id']."'>";
echo "<td>".$historico['ano']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$grau['grau']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$serie['serie']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$curso['curso']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='index.php?option=com_community&view=groups&task=viewgroup&groupid=".$grupo['id']."'>".$grupo['name']."</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$cidade['nome']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$estado['sigla']."</td>";
echo "<td><button class='delete uk-button uk-button-danger'>Delete</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";</tbody></table>
```

file delete.php

```
<?php 

include 'con.php';
$id= $_POST["id"];

$query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM historico WHERE id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());




?>
```

Comment: Is your `id` column a varchar? You are sort of sending it that way with your `'` quotes. If its an integer, you don't need them. Also, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection using depreciated methods. Read the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: did you do any debugging? make sure your php is receiving the posted variable and its content is right. make sure your php can connect to database and execute the delete sentence.

Comment: You have to supply the code that generates every delete button. The delete button id attribute should has the id of the record in your database.

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

this is attempting to read the id of the button that was clicked. You need the id for the tr:

```
var id = row.attr("id");
```

You don't need `:first` either, you just want the `tr` that contains the button:

```
var row = $(this).parents('tr');
```

`parent('tr')` should work, rather than `parents`. (parents probably works but is unnecessary.)

Comment: The mysql library is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO, and prepared statements.

Comment: Print out the value of `id` to check that it is correct. You can use `console.log(id);` and read it in your browser's console. You should be checking the console for errors anyway. And, of course, you've attached the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Make things more simpler print the id in each delete button.

```
echo "<td><button class='delete uk-button uk-button-danger' id='".$historico['id']."'>Delete</button></td>";
```

And then use your code as it is.

> **As Andy G said** You have to remove or modify the id attribute value of your tr

Comment: ..not forgetting to remove this id form the tr element.

Comment: @AndyG More details please! I could not catch what do you mean.

Comment: id's must be unique on the page. If you don't remove it from the tr then it will be duplicated. Personally, I would leave the id on the tr element, as this element needs to be located anyway.

Comment: Andy, you're right, I mean, it worked as you both said now. I just print the id each delete button. Thanks guys.